# Wygwam error after upgrade

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam

I've upgraded a site to EE 2.7.3 and upgraded Wygwam to 3.2.2 , but now when I try and edit or publish a new entry, I get the error below:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Wygwam_helper::custom_toolbar() in /var/www/vhosts/adaptservices.ie/httpdocs/system_adapt/expressionengine/third_party/_wygwam/ft.wygwam.php on line 478

The module seems ok, I access it's settings, just not the channel entries where it's used.

The upgrade went fine offline, but the error appeared when I moved the site online.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: It looks like itw as looking for some files in the old pre update wygwam folder, removing that seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is coming from a “_wygwam” folder. When updating did you rename your old folder to that? Probably just need to delete it.

Comment: Hi Brandon, that was it exactly.  When updating I renamed the folder _wygwam , deleting that folder entirely has fixed the issue.  Lesson Learned.  Thanks for you help.